# How to use psycopg2.extras.execute_values

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a DF like this

where I have converted ***expiry*** column from string to date time as

> df["expiry"] = pd.to_datetime(df["expiry"])

```
  instrument_token  exchange_token  tradingsymbol       name        expiry              strike  lot_size    instrument_type segment     exchange
0  13873410         54193           AARTIIND21JUL800CE  AARTIIND    2021-07-29 00:00:00 800     850         CE              NFO-OPT         NFO
0  13873666         54194           AARTIIND21JUL800PE  AARTIIND    2021-07-29 00:00:00 800     850         PE              NFO-OPT         NFO
0  13873922         54195           AARTIIND21JUL810CE  AARTIIND    2021-07-29 00:00:00 810     850         CE              NFO-OPT         NFO
0  13874178         54196           AARTIIND21JUL810PE  AARTIIND    2021-07-29 00:00:00 810     850         PE              NFO-OPT         NFO
0  13874434         54197           AARTIIND21JUL820CE  AARTIIND    2021-07-29 00:00:00 820     850         CE              NFO-OPT         NFO
```

and I am getting the error

```
invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NaT"
LINE 1: ...aN'::float,'NaN'::float,'NaN'::float,'NaN'::float,'NaT'::tim...
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

code snippet is given below

```
import psycopg2.extras as extras

def execute_values(conn, df, table):
    # Create a list of tupples from the dataframe values
    tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
    # Comma-separated dataframe columns
    cols = ','.join(list(df.columns))
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #create a temp table to handle primary key conflict
    command= '''CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _symbol (
        instrument_token INTEGER NOT NULL, exchange_token INTEGER, tradingsymbol TEXT NOT NULL, name TEXT,
        expiry TIMESTAMP, strike INTEGER, lot_size INTEGER,instrument_type TEXT, segment TEXT NOT NULL, exchange TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (instrument_token,
        tradingsymbol));'''
    query_main = '''INSERT INTO {table}(instrument_token, exchange_token, tradingsymbol, name, expiry, strike, lot_size,instrument_type, segment, exchange )
                SELECT * FROM _symbol
                ON CONFLICT (instrument_token, tradingsymbol)
                DO NOTHING
            '''.format(table=table)

    try:
        cursor.execute(command)
        query_temp = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES %%s " % ('_symbol', cols)
        extras.execute_values(cursor, query_temp, tuples)
        cursor.execute(query_main)
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()
    else:
        cursor.close()
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

[image]

data inside tuple while debugging is also timestamp :(

[image]

Comment: The issue is `to_datetime` can't parse all the strings and in those cases is returning `NaT`. That value is not a legitimate value for a Postgres timestamp so it is being rejected. I don't see anything here [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) that allows you to set that to `None\Null` automatically. Looks like you will have to at some point in the process create code to convert `NaT` to `None\NULL`.

Comment: But I need the date (Timestamp type) in "expiry" column. If even if I convert it to None somehow, it won't be much helpful for me. Is there any other way convert string to timestamp?

Comment: I have tried using .astype('datetime64[ns]'), but result is still the same

Comment: I don't see in your example where you provide `format=` or set ` infer_datetime_format=True`. Is that a copy and paste error or did you not provide that information to the function? See the `to_datetime` link I posted in my previous comment for more information.

Comment: I didn't use format or  infer_datetime_format=True in the code before. have tried adding them now, but error is still the same. In fact, when I print df.info(), it shows me the expiry column as datetime64[ns] (added a screenshot in post)

Comment: datetime type is what you want. Are any of the values for expiry in the dataframe/tuple NaT?

Comment: unfortunately yes! got it. thanks a lot. there are 4 "empty" rows. let me figure out a way to drop those now :(